# Converting Decimal to Timesamp issue

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

I am new to the Data Stage.
My question is: how to convert decimal value into Timestamp? I had got a few of ideas but the tricky part is the incoming value might have:
- 16 digits (real example:2101202016241758), 
- or 15 digits (real example 210120201924111).

I would appreciate any idea on that.

Kind Regards,
Arek

Comment: Why 15 digits? Is the 0 at the end missing? Any other strange variations?

Comment: I do not know what is missing. But if we assume both variations are correct what would be your idea for resolving the issue? DecimalToTimestamp with map '%dd%mm%yyyy%hh%nn%ss.2 works fine for 16 digits but not for 15 digits.

Comment: Not knowing the problem is not an option if you want a solution. Find someone who can tell you the background of the 15 digits. I am not willing to guess.